# Using suppress() throws exception in Kafka Stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here is my code:

```
kStream
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofDays(1L)).grace(Duration.ofMillis(0)))//interval recurrence by daily
    .count(Named.as("countOfLoginFixedInterval"))
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .map((k,v)->{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date(k.window().start())));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            d = new Date();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return KeyValue.pair(new LoginByAccountAndHourOfDay(k.key(),d),new LoginCountsByAccountAndHourOfDay(k.key(),
                d,v));
    },Named.as("transformToLoginCountsByAccountAndDate"))
    .print(Printed.<LoginByAccountAndHourOfDay, LoginCountsByAccountAndHourOfDay>toSysOut().withLabel("Login-KStream"));
    ;
```

When I use `.suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))` throws exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?